# Error code : #1064 MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Error statement :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE = MEMORY' at line 6

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
srnum INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
samay TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
lat VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
lon VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = MEMORY ;
```

Comment: You have an extra comma before the parenthesy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the extra comma(,) from end of 5th line. The SQL should be like:

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( 
    srnum INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    samay TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
    lat VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , 
    lon VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MEMORY ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma before the parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( 
    srnum INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    samay TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
    lat VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , 
    lon VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MEMORY ;
```